# Unit and integration testing in web development is different?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, integration-testing

I am pretty confuse with unit and integration testing of traditional software development and web development. I have seen many different answer and explanation of it.

The Web Engineering textbook says about unit and integration testing for web application: 
Unit testing: Testing on single web page as opposed to testing single function 
Integration testing: Testing on flow of data from one web page to another (and linkage)

while the software engineering textbook defines unit testing and integration testing as followed. 
unit testing: Testing on smallest unit 
integration testing: Testing on interaction between unit or module

Hope someone can clarify to me which is the correct one.

Comment: Which "web engineering textbook" and which "software engineering textbook"?

Comment: Web Engineering by Emilia Mendes, Nile Mosley (pg 219). As for the general definition of unit and integration testing, I believe it is defined the same as in most of the book in the market

Comment: Anyway, the software engineering book is correct. If "web engineering" people want a term that means "test a single page", then they should invent one instead of attempting to corrupt an existing word.

Answer (score 2):

The "web engineering" textbook is... likely wrong.  That's not what those words mean to most folks.

**Unit testing**: testing the smallest possible bits of functionality, independently.  For Java, something like the JUnit framework is used to do this.  You often try to test just *one* class, and you may fake it's dependencies using something like Mockito, so you're really testing just one thing.

**Integration Testing**: testing several parts of the system together.  This may be a small integration test (testing multiple classes without mocking), or something large, like making sure that your webserver is connecting to a database correctly.

**End-to-End Testing**: the biggest Integration test; this is basically standing up every part of your system and running scripts that look like fake users.  Selenium is a tool used for this.